# Using chrome.tabs.executeScript to check a box, not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to get the checkbox in this page to be checked.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="f">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> 1<br /></li>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My popup.js is below:

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.body.f.vehicle.checked='true'"});
  window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
  }
});
```

In the console log I keep getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vehicle' of undefined.**

My popup.html is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Set Page Color Popup</title>
    <style>
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background: white;
    }

    div:first-child {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }

    div {
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1px 3px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      width: 100px;
      margin-top: 1px;
      background: #cccccc;
    }
    div:hover {
      background: #aaaaaa;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">1</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
document.f.vehicle.checked='true';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PnXsE/

Comment: I tried that (document.f.vehicle.checked='true';) even. I still get the exact same error.